# Combine two arrays in Bash line by line

Tags: arrays, bash

I have 2 arrays in BASH and I want to combine them line by line i.e.

```
arr1=( 1 2 3 4 )
arr2=( 5 6 7 8 )
```

When simply adding one array to another it's like `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8` and I want the output of this combination to be `1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8` (line by line)

Any advice?

Comment: There are no "lines" in your description.  Do you want the array `(1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8)`, or do you want the string `1\n5\n2\n6\n3\n7\n4\n8\n`?

Comment: hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr1=( 1 2 3 4 )
arr2=( 5 6 7 8 )

declare -a result

resultIndex=0
for index in ${!arr1[*]}; do
  result[$resultIndex]=${arr1[$index]} 
  let "resultIndex++"
  result[$resultIndex]=${arr2[$index]} 
  let "resultIndex++"
done

echo "${result[@]}"
```